# Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, android

I already added the correct from GoogleAdMob but it's still showing the error!
I am using firbase first time
Please help!
ThankYou :)

2020-07-20 02:13:21.137 17360-17360/com.example.expensemanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.expensemanager, PID: 17360
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
```

Comment: the error is because you have to add metadata in your manifest file and make sure you add your app id key generated from admob

Answer (score 0):

just give a check meta-data tag is out of activity tag

if it is like this

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity>
            <meta-data> 
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
                android:value="ca-app-pub-4347201915048498~6120388314"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

this should be changed to this

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity>
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4347201915048498~6120388314"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your manifest file , inside the application tag put this code

```
<application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
             
            /// pass the key generated from your admob which contains ~(APP ID)
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/> // 
    </application>
```